# how to set camera size, and show the preview in a small part of the screen

Tags: android, image, parameters, camera, photo

Hi I need to set a costum camera (in a small surfaceview or in something else) and i need to set the preview and also the photo(after taken) just in the small box. I want to know if it's possible or not in android.

Comment: This is possible in android.

Comment: ok...how can i do? some tutorial?

Comment: @FabioBalsamo: Were you able to do this ? If yes, can you please share some code ?

Answer (score 0):

Just define the View that displays camera preview as 20×20 do, or whatever you want. Probably you want to adjust this view size (`getLayoutParams().width` and `…height`) after you choose the camera parameters, to fit the aspect ratio.